# Rounding a double to the nearest of two doubles

Tags: java, math, rounding

Is there a method to round a double the nearest of two doubles?

e.g.:

I want to round numbers to the nearest between 3.3 and 3.7.. so:

```
3.4 --> 3.3
3.472 --> 3.3
3.5 --> 3.7
3.573 --> 3.7
```

And so on...

Is there a method to do that?

Comment: That's totally insane. No algorithm is found in this question! How do you suppose us to sometimes, round it to floor and sometimes ceil it :/ Use an if else condition, and change the value yourself.

Comment: Is it possible. Yes, sure! Try a little, coding is fun.

Comment: `if(x >= (min+max)/2) x = max; else x = min;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such method. However, writing your own shouldn't present a great difficulty:

```
static double nearest(double val, double left, double right) {
    return Math.abs(val-left) <= Math.abs(val-right) ? left : right;
}
```

Comment: Fine, though (for the pedantic) for `nearest(0.5, 0.0, 1.0)` I woould rather see `1.0`, so take `<`.